# How to get GD2 generate PNG8 when resizing PNG8 images

Tags: 8

I have an image field which accepts `jpg, jpeg, png`. I've chosen the `Image style: Medium` on the display of that field. That style is configured at `/admin/config/media/image-styles/manage/medium` and it simply scales the image to 600px width.

On `/admin/config/media/image-toolkit` I can see that GD2 is being used.

My problem is that if the original image on that field is PNG8, the rendered thumbnail (by GD2) is PNG24. This results in much larger file for no reason.

Shouldn't GD2 respect the fact that the source is PNG8? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: FWIW I switched to `Imagick image manipulation toolkit` and it also has the same problematic behavior. Thumbnails generated from PNG8 images are in PNG24 format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GD2 indeed doesn't check what palette size is the source image. From `GDToolkit.php`:

```
// Always save PNG images with full transparency.
if ($this->getType() == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
  imagealphablending($this->getResource(), FALSE);
  imagesavealpha($this->getResource(), TRUE);
}
```

The only way I could hack PNG8 in there was:

```
// Always save PNG images with full transparency.
if ($this->getType() == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
  imagealphablending($this->getResource(), FALSE);
  imagesavealpha($this->getResource(), TRUE);
  imagetruecolortopalette($this->getResource(), TRUE, 256); // ← hardcoded 256 hack for PNG8
}
```

I couldn't find a way of determining the palette size of the source image. So by leaving that hack of mine in there the risk is that PNG24 source images will be saved in the `styles/` directory as PNG8 files.